# IPv4 Client <-> IPv6 Server - Tunnel from client to server to use IPv6

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, tunneling

I have a Debian server with a IPv6 Tunnel (from sixxs) and an IPv4 Ubuntu Client. Now i want to make a tunnel from the client to the server, so that i can surf with IPv6 from the client.

Is there a simple solution or should i request another tunnel (ar a subnet) for my client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SixXS only provide a single IPv6 address with a tunnel. Because in IPv6 it is not possible to NAT, you will require a subnet in order to route your other machine through the tunnel.

Is the other machine on the same LAN? If so, the best thing to do is to request a subnet from SixXS and route a /64 from the /48 subnet you are allocated onto your LAN.

If the machine is on a separate Internet connection, it would probably be more economical to request another tunnel, although requesting a SixXS subnet and routing it yourself via something like OpenVPN is not infeasible either.

Comment: The machine is in the same LAN. So i go to request a subnet. Thanks for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider getting a tunnel with [Hurricane Electric](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/), which will provide you with a routed /64. Then you could (in theory) set up a VPN.

The easiest option would, indeed, probably be to get a second tunnel from SixXS. An [anything-in-anything](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/ayiya/) tunnel would be a good option for your Ubuntu client. Or terminate another routed tunnel locally at your router, or use [6to4](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/6to4), or... the options are endless. ;-)